# C# : avoids display flickering

Tags: drawing

I'm working on a C# project in which I draw on a tabPage of a tabControl several geometric form to display a music score (see picture). I update regularly the drawing. I had a flicker in the display.
To correct this, I added this function and It works :

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

But if the user has redimentioned the form, the flickering comes back. What can I do to correct this.
Thanks in advance.

[drawing][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilyMv.png

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've fix my own problem with theses lines :

```
tabPageLearn.GetType().GetMethod("SetStyle", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(tabPageLearn, new object[]
{
    System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
    System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
    ystem.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true
});
```

With "tabPageLearn", the name of the tabPage